# What is use of assaigning subclass object to superclass reference variable

Tags: java

This is from docs

> If you consider the above program, you can instantiate the class as
> given below. But using the superclass reference variable ( cal in this
> case) you cannot call the method multiplication(), which belongs to
> the subclass My_Calculation.

```
Calculation demo = new My_Calculation();
demo.addition(a, b);
demo.Subtraction(a, b);
```

**My doubt is :**

What is use for assigning subclass object to a superclass variable , If I cant even able to access members of the object

Comment: Because in your subclass you can override some methods from superclass and make them do a little different things. Then you can pass that class to some function which can't be modified by you but it will use your overrided method

Comment: @luk2302 mentions the main reason, programming for the most general notion, so the program covers the most, and objects can be implemented differently. This no longer holds when functionality is added by extending a class. That however is a questionable use of inheritance. Java `String` cannot be extended (fortunately), as it would certainly have invoked numerous child instances.